# Next statement in a While Loop with PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

Ok i have a while loop function in my site that pulls in excel documents and parses them to the database i want to check for duplicates and if duplicate skip it:

```
$content = file($selectfile1);

$posted_content = array();
list($rownum, $row) = each($content);
$posted_content[0] = explode(",", $row);
array_push($posted_content[0], "ID");
$count = 0;
// iterate each row (1 post)
while (list($rownum, $row) = each($content))
{
    $count++;

    $cols = "orderid, created_at, updated_at, notification_type, radius, available, expiration, ";
    $vals = "";
    $cols2 = "equipment_id";
    $vals2 = "";

....{parsing data)...
}
```

i want to write in a script that checks to see if the record is a duplicate and if not enter it.

```
$sql25 = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE origin =" . $origin_id . " user_id =12039";
$rs25 = $conn->Execute($sql25);
if($rs25->RecordCount() == 1 || $rs25->RecordCount() >= 1)
    {



here is where i need a command. Can you use? next()
--------------------------------------------------


    }
else
{
         Insert query
    }
```

Comment: do you mean 'continue'?

Comment: is continue the command in php that will go to next loop

Comment: Yes...................

Comment: ok thanks if you want to post as answer i will accept it thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [`continue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) statement.

From the docs:

> `continue` is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

example:

```
<?php
while ( ... ) {
    if ($foo = 'bar') {
        // skip to the next iteration
        continue;
    }
}
```